# How can I undo this Base64 encoding? (Scala)

Tags: string, scala, encoding, base64, bytebuffer

I have a piece of code which does some encoding like so:

```
def byteBufferToString(b: ByteBuffer): String = java.util.Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(bb.array)
```

I'd also like another method which does the opposite. Here's a few of my attempts:

```
def stringToByteBuffer(str: String): ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder.decode(str))

def stringToByteBuffer(str: String): ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

def stringToByteBuffer(str: String): ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder.decode(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
```

But none of these seems to satisfy the condition:

```
byteBufferToString(stringToByteBuffer(testString)) == testString
```

For example, when testString is `abc`, I get something like `= abc=` instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/3nwROXJFQzqzKIW5YfaJqg/3